# how can i pass argument to bash in exec command?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, hue

I have a bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash
./buind/env/hue shell -i python -c 'exec open("my.py").read,{"pars":[$1,$2]})'
```

the program gives error **$1,$2 invalid syntax** it doesnt take my args.( i try `${1},${2}` or with double quotes)

When i `echo` **my params** in sh it shows my params correct.

i run **sh** : `./my.sh "mypar1" "mypar2"`

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: "'$1'" works thanks

Comment: It doesn't work _safely_; you have serious security problems if you go that route and your arguments come from somewhere less trusted than your source code.

Comment: If you use `python -c '...' "$@"` your arguments will be available in `sys.argv`.

Comment: (you can use `__import__("sys").argv[1:]` in place of `[$1,$2]` if you want to keep it all one command inside the Python interpreter; run `python -c 'print(repr(__import__("sys").argv))' one two three` to understand how/why this works).

Comment: Are you actually using Python 2? `exec` is a function in Python 3, not a statement: `exec('...')`.

Comment: You are in a context of single quotes here. Therefore, the shell does not expand $1 and $2.

Comment: no I use python 3 @chepner

Comment: @CompEng If you are, then `exec open...` should be a (different) syntax error, because Python 3 doesn't have an `exec` statement.